# SharePoint 2010 configuration wizard fails at step 8

Tags: error, configuration-wizard

I am getting following error:

```
Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type System.TypeLoadException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIdentifierType' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIdentifierType' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SPAclFormatter.Deserialize[TRights](XmlReader xmlReader, SPAcl`1 acl)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SPAclFormatter.Deserialize[TRights](String serializedAcl)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Install()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.ProvisionServiceApplicationsAndProxies()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be basically some patch update issue. Are you running the configuration wizard for the first time?

There is a [technet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/09/19/update-on-september-security-bulletin-ms11-074-and-sharepoint-2010-issues.aspx) for some better understanding, where it says KB2560890 could be the issue. No guarantees though.

Do you have SharePoint SP1 installed? Have you updated to the latest cumulative update for SharePoint. Better apply all the latest patches and cumulative updates and this should get resolved.